# Disassembly window in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate is not showing

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, disassembly

I am just starting to work with the debugger of my Visual Studio and have the following problem: When I start the debugger, the Disassembly window is just not there!

Here is an image of my Windows section of Debug menu:

[screenshot](http://i46.tinypic.com/2dw6cme.png)

I am wondering if this wasn't an optional install?

Comment: It's pretty out of whack.  Tools + Import/Export + Reset.

Comment: I had the same problem- the settings I'd used since '05 were still fine but importing the file meant that I didn't see the Disassembly option under Windows. <br/> Resetting fixed it, thanks. Now to redo years of adjustments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't paste a picture, but if you rightclick on the source when at a break point you will see `goto disassembly` in the menu options.